# How to access a function with synonyms names in intellisense help in C#?

Tags: c#, intellisense

Is there a way to declare a function in a class then access through multiple synonyms?

I have created a function with the name `Edit()` in my C# class. Is it possible to access this function with the following names using Visual Studio intellisense?

```
EditChanges()
Update()
```

Comment: Do you want to be advised by Intellisense of Edit existance when you start typing obj.Update or what? If so I don't think the Intellisense can be that Intelli :) Moreover, what if you have all of them at once?

Comment: I would ask - why do you want to do this? What is the problem you're trying to solve? Having multiple names for the same method call can lead to a confusing API that makes it harder for developers to work with (i.e. What's the difference between Edit() and EditChanges()) - causing them to have to dig to find the answer.

Comment: @Ian: That was my first thought, though on second though, it could actually be a helpful feature. I'm not sure whether the OP wants to actually add more method names to the API; if I understand the question correctly, it's rather about not knowing what a particular member is called, but having several synonymous words in mind that might describe the feature. Being able to input either of these and then being pointed to the actual `Edit()` method by IntelliSense would actually make sense while working with APIs that one is unfamiliar with IMHO.

Comment: You can always implement `ICompletionSourceProvider ` and write own extension for IntelliSense :)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Yeah, maybe... In which case I would have thought a visual studio extension would be the way to go. Where you use XML markup to define <synonyms> and you modify intelli-sense to pick these up and show alternatives (maybe in brackets like: Update() => Edit()). Doesn't sound trivial though

Comment: @Ian: Indeed, either as a part of the Xml comments, or as a custom attribute.

Comment: Well, we're talking about Intellisense, i.e. picking from a list of methods of a class, or classes in a namespace...
In fact, if your API is so big that you can't just poke in the list of all the class' methods (or namespace's classes) looking for something, then, maybe, it's a time for refactoring?